# Sass --watch all files in entire dierctory and child dierctory?

Tags: sass

I've tried *.css, but it doesn't work. Is there a command for this or something?

Comment: Sass does watch all files in the specified directory and its subdirectories, can you be more specific as to the full command you are using?